# Jaydata relationships can work without save?

Tags: javascript, jaydata

I'm trying to have a simple model with Parent -> Childs (correctly declared and working i think).

I do this:

```js
var parent = new $data.Types.Parent();
$data.context.Parents.add(parent);
parent.Code = 123;

var child = new $data.Types.Child();
$data.context.Childs.add(child);
child.Parent = parent;
child.Value = 456;
```

But then when i try to access parent.Childs, it is undefined, not the array containing the added child.

So, after saving both of them with:

```js
$data.context.saveChanges();
```

Then accesing again, parent.Childs, i get the array [ Child ]

Coming from other ORM tools, it seems jaydata doesn't supports accessing relationships before saving?

Any help will be appreciated! Cheers.

**EDIT:**

Looking at other stackoverflow code, it seems i must create the Childs array by hand, i mean:

```js
var parent = new $data.Types.Parent();
$data.context.Parents.add(parent);
parent.Code = 123;
parent.Childs = new Array();

var child = new $data.Types.Child();
$data.context.Childs.add(child);
child.Parent = parent;
child.Value = 456;

parent.Childs.push(child);
```

Anybody can confirm me this as THE way to use relationships in jaydata?

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the child to parent. Setting the parent id of the child will not add the child to an other array.

Comment: As i just posted; Please confirm me?

Comment: You do not have to create the array but you have to add your child object to it. Sorry, no black magic is built into JayData :)

Comment: By "you do not have to create the array", you mean i can avoid doing parent.Childs = new Array() ? Cause in my testing, if i dont, then an error will raise when trying to do the line parent.Childs.push(child); i get an error like this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

Comment: I beleive that you shouldn't have to manually create the array... I'll test it and fill a bug if needed

Comment: Could u confirm this is a bug?

Comment: this is how JayData works.. let's call this a feature